# using either 2-propanol or isopropyl alcohol for writing a report

Tags: experimental-chemistry, nomenclature

I'm writing a report based on testing I've done on a material. I'm wondering if there is any convention on using different nomenclature for isopropanol. Which way of writing this molecule is consider the most accepted or the most "correct?"

Comment: The answer depends on the audience. For theoretical, more nomenclature inclined chemists, I would use the preferred IUPAC name propan-2-ol,  but technicians would probably use isopropanol or isopropyl alcohol.

Answer (score 1):

Many compounds can have more than one systematic IUPAC name. A compound may be named correctly in two or more ways in accordance with the several methods recommended by IUPAC.

However, “isopropanol” is one of the rare cases of a widespread name that is actually considered *wrong* and not just *not preferred*.

> Designations such as isopropanol, sec-butanol, and tert-butanol are incorrect because there are no hydrocarbons isopropane, sec-butane, and tert-butane to which the suffix "-ol" can be added; such names should be abandoned.

– *Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry (The IUPAC 'Blue Book'), Sections A, B, C, D, E, F, and H.* Oxford: Pergamon Press. 1979.

Isopropyl alcohol, however, is correct but not preferred.

> Isopropyl alcohol, sec-butyl alcohol, and tert-butyl alcohol are, however, permissible (see Rule C-201.3) because the radicals isopropyl, sec-butyl, and tert-butyl do exist.

– ibid.

The preferred name in accordance with the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)* is **propan-2-ol.**